# How to modify an attribute which have a no-primitive data type with JMX?

Tags: java, swing, jmx, jconsole, mbeans

I would like to know if it's possible to modify java.awt.Color attribute through the jConsole.
I have a class like this :

```
public class MyColor implements MyColorMBean {
    private Color background;

    public Color getBackground() {
        return background;
    }

    public void setBackground(Color background) {
        this.background = background;
    }
}
```

which implements this MBean :

```
public interface MyColorMBean {
    public Color getBackground();
    public void setBackground(Color background);
}
```

and when I try to set another value for background (like Color.GREEN for example), it doesn't work... but when I set the type of background to String, it works!

Is it possible to change a no-primitive data type with JMX?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation in console. If you used a programmatic interface, it would work. I would add Color and String type methods to the Mean (with different names).

Comment: Hi Nicholas, thank you for your answer :) but what do you want to say about a programmatic interface? Do I have to use an adaptor or something like that other than JConsole?

Comment: Hi Baptiste; A programmatic client like this one http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jmx/examples/Basic/Client.java could do what you outlined. JConsole is simply limited in interpreting the String values you enter into the target type.